# Can you have a salesforce community with multiple Single Sign on Configurations?

Tags: community, single-sign-on, saml, office-365, azure

Our organization is has multiple clients that we support. We would like to have one community that they all log into for technical support. We have our company's single sign on set up successfully with O365 as the IDP, and tried duplicating the settings with our clients who also use O365. However, it always fails to log them in. Is it possible to have multiple different SSO configurations logging into the same community and Entity ID? If not, what else could we do to achieve our goal.

Thank you for reading and hopefully for helping us out.